# Atrun command in macos is not starting

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, macintosh

I'm learning the 'at' command in macOS. However, my 'at' command jobs are getting scheduled but never executing. For example, when I run a simple command like `echo "hello world" | at 9:30 AM`, it doesn't produce any output. I also attempted to create a directory, but it didn't work as expected. Here's the script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir at_file
touch at_file/files{001..100}.txt
```

I believe there might be an issue related to the atrun service or some other configuration specific to macOS. If my understanding is correct, I would appreciate guidance on how to resolve this issue specifically for macOS.

I have also tried the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

First, I tried unloading and loading the atrun service using the following commands:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

However, when I ran the second command, it displayed 'ALREADY RUNNING' as the output.

Then, I attempted to stop and start the atrun service with these commands:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.atrun
sudo launchctl start com.apple.atrun
```

But when I checked the status using launchctl list | grep com.apple.atrun, it didn't produce any output.

Finally, I ran the at -l command to list all job IDs and scripts, but the jobs never executed.

It seems that despite scheduling the jobs with the 'at' command, they are not executing as expected. I'm unsure why this is happening and would appreciate any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue

Comment: You did not show how you asked `at` to run the script.

Comment: Did you search everywhere for `at_file` directory? It may not be where you think it will be.

Comment: The `at` job should run in the directory you queued it from, but it is always wise to use specific directories in the command or in the script itself. You say you could see the jobs scheduled but they never execute. Do they disappear from the schedule at their scheduled time? If so, the scheduler is working, and removed them after at least attempting to run them.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

(a) The `echo` sends the text `hello world` into the pipe, and `at` stores this as the command to be run. The command `hello` does not exist, so the job fails. You might fix this with `echo "echo hello world" | at 9:30 AM`. Personally, I prefer to enter my commands to be executed as a HereDoc.

(b) The `at` system does not know which terminal set up the job; the at job can also have been set up by a background script; and any terminal may in any case have been closed between setting up the job and executing it. So the job has nowhere to send the output. `at` jobs have stdin connected to /dev/null. Generally, stdout and stderr are emailed to the job owner unless redirected.

EDIT: With stuff that works in the background, take baby steps. Log it all, prove it was actually run (and when), stuff it with debug, and post what actually happened.

If this creates ~/Debug.atjob, you have a working `at` system. If not, that's the time to start messing with the installation, not before.

Also, note that `now + 1 minute` gets rounded down to a whole minute. `at` is part of the `cron` package, which only has one-minute discrimination. You would probably have noticed if `cron` was not functioning.

```
$ ls -l ~/Debug.atjob at_file
ls: cannot access '/home/paul/Debug.atjob': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'at_file': No such file or directory
$ cat atBug
#! /bin/bash

{
    pwd
    date '+Began at %T'
    mkdir at_file
    echo "Status mkdir $?"
    ls -ld at_file
    touch at_file/files{001..100}.txt
    echo "Status touch $?"
    echo 'First three'
    ls -l at_file | head -n 3
    echo 'Last three'
    ls -l at_file | tail -n 3
    date '+Ended at %T'
} > ~/Debug.atjob 2>&1

$ date; echo './atBug' | at now + 1 minute; atq
Tue 18 Jul 09:06:48 BST 2023
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 45 at Tue Jul 18 09:07:00 2023
45  Tue Jul 18 09:07:00 2023 a paul
$ sleep 60
$ cat ~/Debug.atjob
/home/paul
Began at 09:07:01
Status mkdir 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 paul paul 4096 Jul 18 09:07 at_file
Status touch 0
First three
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 0 Jul 18 09:07 files001.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 0 Jul 18 09:07 files002.txt
Last three
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 0 Jul 18 09:07 files098.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 0 Jul 18 09:07 files099.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul paul 0 Jul 18 09:07 files100.txt
Ended at 09:07:01
$
```

Comment: I also attempted to create a directory, but it didn't work as expected. Here's the script I used:

#!/bin/bash
mkdir at_file
touch at_file/files{001..100}.txt

I believe there might be an issue related to the atrun service or some other configuration specific to macOS. If my understanding is correct, I would appreciate guidance on how to resolve this issue specifically for macOS.

Comment: @MathewNelson  I don't have MacOS knowledge or availability, but `at` is very generic. Edited to include example of how to (a) show the job was queued, and (b) how to show what happened.